# deleting rows of a numpy array based on uniqueness of a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

let's say I have a bi-dimensional array like that

```
numpy.array(
    [[0,1,1.2,3],
    [1,5,3.2,4],
    [3,4,2.8,4], 
    [2,6,2.3,5]])
```

I want to have an array formed eliminating whole rows based on uniqueness of values of last column, selecting the row to keep based on value of third column.
e.g. in this case i would like to keep only one of the rows with 4 as last column, and choose the one which has the minor value of third column, having something like that as a result:

```
array([0,1,1.2,3],
      [3,4,2.8,4],
      [2,6,2.3,5])
```

thus eliminating row [1,5,3.2,4]

which would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

My numpy is way out of practice, but this should work:

```
#keepers is a dictionary of type int: (int, int)
#the key is the row's final value, and the tuple is (row index, row[2])
keepers = {}
deletions = []
for i, row in enumerate(n):
    key = row[3]
    if key not in keepers:
        keepers[key] = (i, row[2])
    else:
        if row[2] > keepers[key][1]:
            deletions.append(i)
        else:
            deletions.append(keepers[key][0])
            keepers[key] = (i, row[2])
o = numpy.delete(n, deletions, axis=0)
```

I've greatly simplified it from my declarative solution, which was getting quite unwieldy. Hopefully this is easier to follow; all we do is maintain a dictionary of values that we want to keep and a list of indexes we want to delete.

Comment: Add at the end your version with `itertools.groupby()`. It is interesting.

Comment: I'll be a bit more precise: it's wrong in an algorithmic way. In order to work, I was going to need to sort the array, which is something I really want to avoid in order to keep the runtime down to O(n), which this solution should be

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved efficiently in Numpy by combining `lexsort` and `unique` as follows

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 1.2, 3], 
              [1, 5, 3.2, 4],
              [3, 4, 2.8, 4], 
              [2, 6, 2.3, 5]])

# Sort by last column and 3rd column when values are equal
j = np.lexsort(a.T)

# Find first occurrence (=smallest 3rd column) of unique values in last column
k = np.unique(a[j, -1], return_index=True)[1]

print(a[j[k]])
```

This returns the desired result

```
[[ 0.   1.   1.2  3. ]
 [ 3.   4.   2.8  4. ]
 [ 2.   6.   2.3  5. ]]
```